# Nifi change flowfile name to unique number

Tags: apache-nifi

My consumekafka processor is generating flowfile name which is alphanumeric, I tried converting it into number as I have to write it to hdfs and need number instead of alphanumeric value -using `${now():toNumber()}`
the number that is getting generated is not unique value and these records are getting failed to write to HDFS because of same filename. How can I get a unique filename that is not alphanumeric?

Comment: strange requirement. you could try `nextInt()` or `random()` - but they could repeat once in a while. why you can't have alphanumeric?

Comment: i cant have alphanumeric because the final table in which data is getting loaded has defined that column as process id which is int. nextInt() is generating same numbers sometimes. Can you please suggest any other thing.

Comment: Try to make updateattribute to run in one thread and not in a batch mode...

Comment: Another idea to combine nextInt and random: `${nextInt()}${random():mod(1000):padLeft(3,'0')}` - have no environment to test it...